# Java Xpath NameSpace Parsing

Tags: xpath, namespaces

Although I saw similar posts, I can't seem to solve this problem (so I am parsing the xml by hand and not using an xpath expression)... This is the XML I have...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:tnew="http://PR_Library/TNeWebService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tnew:ApercuenRequest>
         <tnew:OpcionCarga>0</tnew:OpcionCarga>
         <tnew:Sucursal>1</tnew:Sucursal>
         <tnew:Vendedor>8000</tnew:Vendedor>
         <tnew:CanalConsulta>1</tnew:CanalConsulta>
         <tnew:UsuarioCarga>8000</tnew:UsuarioCarga>
         <tnew:Comercio>0</tnew:Comercio>
         <tnew:FechaEvaluacion>20140109</tnew:FechaEvaluacion>
         <tnew:ModeloDeEvaluacion></tnew:ModeloDeEvaluacion> 
         <tnew:IdEvaluacion>3694852</tnew:IdEvaluacion>
         <tnew:Dudosa>0</tnew:Dudosa>
         <tnew:Exceptuado>1</tnew:Exceptuado>
         <tnew:TipoDocumento>1</tnew:TipoDocumento>
         <tnew:NumeroDocumento>5881040</tnew:NumeroDocumento>
         <tnew:Sexo>F</tnew:Sexo>
         <tnew:Rol>5</tnew:Rol>
         <tnew:RelacionLaboral>5</tnew:RelacionLaboral>
         <tnew:TipoEmpleado>0</tnew:TipoEmpleado>
         <tnew:FechaIngresoEmpleo></tnew:FechaIngresoEmpleo>
         <tnew:AntiguedadLaboral>0</tnew:AntiguedadLaboral>
         <tnew:IngresoMensualAnalista>0</tnew:IngresoMensualAnalista>
         <tnew:IngresoMensual>6000</tnew:IngresoMensual>
         <tnew:EstadoCivil>4</tnew:EstadoCivil>
         <tnew:FechaDeNacimiento>19540423</tnew:FechaDeNacimiento>
         <tnew:SituacionVivienda>3</tnew:SituacionVivienda>
         <tnew:DomicilioProvincia></tnew:DomicilioProvincia>
         <tnew:DomicilioLocalidad></tnew:DomicilioLocalidad>
         <tnew:NivelEstudios></tnew:NivelEstudios>
         <tnew:RelacionConTN>1</tnew:RelacionConTN>
         <tnew:FechaAltaAbogado></tnew:FechaAltaAbogado>
         <tnew:MarcaAbogado>N</tnew:MarcaAbogado>
         <tnew:Cdi></tnew:Cdi>
         <tnew:Campana></tnew:Campana>
        </tnew:ApercuenRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the following Java code...

```
private XPathFactory xpathFactory = null;  
private XPath xpath = null; 
private DocumentBuilderFactory factory = null; 
private DocumentBuilder builder= null;                                              
private XPathExpression expr;
private Node nodo = null;
private Node nodoAux = null;
private NodeList result = null;
private NodeList nodeList = null;

...

            try {
            xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
            factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builder= factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            NamespaceContext context = new NameSpaceNevada();
            xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }  

...

evaluarExpresion(documentoXML,"/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/tnew:ApercuenRequest/tnew:OpcionCarga")

    private String evaluarExpresion(Document documentoXML, String expresion) throws Exception{
    try {
        expr = xpath.compile(expresion);
        result = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(documentoXML, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println((result.item(0)!=null?result.item(0).getNodeName():"") + " ->>>> " + (result.item(0).getFirstChild()!=null?result.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue():""));
        return result.item(0).getFirstChild()!=null?result.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue():null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I can't seem to get the "0" value as you see it in the XML... I have tried a lot of things... I'll be watching... The thing is, I can parse it manualy but the joke is doing it through xpath expressions so I can save code...

Hope I made me understood...

The `getNamespaceURI` method from the `NameSpaceNevada` object is as follows:

```
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
  if (prefix == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No prefix provided!");
  } else if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
    return "http://univNaSpResolver/book";
  } else if (prefix.equals("soapenv")) {
    return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
  } else if (prefix.equals("tnew")) {
    return "http://PR_Library/TNeWebService";
  } else {
    return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
  }
}
```

Comment: The getNamespaceURI method from the NameSpaceNevada object is as follows...
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No prefix provided!");
        } else if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
        return "http://univNaSpResolver/book";
    } else if (prefix.equals("soapenv")) {
        return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    } else if (prefix.equals("tnew")) {
        return "http://PR_Library/TNeWebService";
    } else {
        return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
  }
}

Comment: I apologize for the indents... I can't post an answer as I am new in the forum...

Comment: To add more information to the question, you use the _edit_ function - you can always edit your own posts, and as you gain reputation you will be able to edit other people's posts too.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than evaluating the expression as a node set and then doing complex DOM manipulations to extract the text value, you could just evaluate the expression as a string in the first place.

```
expr.evaluate(documentoXML);
```

would evaluate the expression and use XPath rules to convert the result to a String, which in this case would give you the text content of the first (in fact the only) `tnew:OpcionCarga` element.

But the real reason why it is not working is that Java's `DocumentBuilderFactory` is *non-namespace-aware* by default (a very bad design decision in many people's eyes, but one that now cannot be corrected without breaking backwards compatibility) - you must do

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

before you call `.newDocumentBuilder()` in order to create a namespace-aware parser.

Comment: Thankx you for answering Ian... I will be trying that... Meanwhile what I did is to "clean" the xml chain and leave without prefixes... I will definitely be trying that... Thankx again

Comment: @user3118724 even if the document doesn't actually use any namespaces you still need to parse it namespace-aware to guarantee that XPath will work.  The XPath language is only defined over namespace-well-formed XML.